# Bash + Pup printing only attribute

Tags: bash, pup

I'm `wget`ing a webpage src code then using `pup` to grab the `<meta>` tag that I need. Now I want to print only the value of the `content` field.

In this case, the output I want is: `https://example.com/my/folder/first.jpg?foo=bar`

```
# wget page to /tmp/output.html
IMAGE_URL=$(cat /tmp/output.html | pup 'meta[property*="og:image"]')
echo $IMAGE_URL is:
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/my/folder/first.jpg?foo=bar">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wget -O /tmp/output.html --user-agent="user-agent: Whatever..." https://example.com/somewhere
IMAGE_URL=$(cat /tmp/output.html | pup --plain 'meta[property*="og:image"]' | sed -n 's/.*content=\"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr{content}` to only get the content of the attribute.

```
wget -O /tmp/output.html --user-agent="user-agent: Whatever..." https://example.com/somewhere
IMAGE_URL=$(cat /tmp/output.html | pup 'meta[property*="og:image"] attr{content}'
```